# How to Create a virtual calculated column in Laravel Migration from another table?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, migrate

**Table to be created the virtual calculated column.
The total column is just an example of what I expect**

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('price');
    $table->integer('total')->virtualAs(sum(lots.total))->defalt(0); // virtualAs Or virtualAs
});
```

Second table

```
Schema::create('lots', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('description');
    $table->decimal('price');
    $table->integer('total') ;
    $table->integer('product_id'); //relationship
});
```

**I would like to obtain the sum of the lots in the total product column**

Comment: You can just run two migrations and then run the seeder, which will fill the needed field

Comment: Do you mean that the total column is spelled correctly?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448583/subquery-as-generated-column-in-mysql

Comment: thank you @ChinLeung ! You helped a lot with this post. I'll change the concept regarding the use of virtual columns.

Answer (score -1):

The total should not be stored in the Db since it is redundant and can be calculated.
You should create your table and your models with the relationship for each others.
Then use the [`->withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method to count the related *lots* of *products*.

Ex: `Product::withCount('lots')->get()` this will give you the number of *lots* associated with each *product*

Comment: How do I calculate a column from the lots table with withCount ()?
Can you give an example?

Comment: Have a look here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models